# Manipulating the JS prototype

Tags: javascript

I want to add a $error element to all my objects including "primitive" objects such as string and number.

I have the following codepen which just adds this value (via a function) to the Object class.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nglbL

For convenience, here is the code:-

```
Object.prototype.setError = function (str) {
  this.$error = str;
  this.$errorObj = { };
  console.log("value of object is " + this.toString());
  console.log("Setting error to " + this.$error);  
}; 
Object.prototype.getError = function() { 
  console.log("error is " + this.$error);
  console.log("error object is " + this.$errorObj);
  return this.$error;
}
var obj = { 
    "str" : "string me!",
    "bool" : true,
    "int" : 1 
}

obj.str.setError("error");

console.log("Retriving error and it is " + obj.str.getError());
```

Clearly, I don't understand how the prototypical inheritance works.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `try...catch` and `throw`?

Comment: I'm 97% sure this is caused by the fact that there is a difference between a string _literal_ and a string _object_, since he is using `obj.str` and not `obj` in his code...

Comment: The real question here is what are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want EVERY object to have these methods? You realize that this will propagate to EVERYTHING in javascript (i.e. Array, function, etc) since they all have Object.prototype in their chain

Comment: @tkone I was just playing at this point. You are correct that I would probably only want to apply it to specific types (objects, arrays, numbers, strings and booleans).

Comment: @Blender I am playing with angular and I want to take error messages from the server (which would have a specific path) and create a directive to handle these server errors. Not sure how well that would work, but thought it was worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript primitives are wrapped in background by its Object counterparts, these objects are called "Wrapper Objects", every time you treat a primitive as an object, a new wrapper object is created. This process occurs transparently, and a variable holding a string primitive doesn't hold a reference to an object, but the literal string value. 
Wrapper objects won't survive for multiple uses! So, just don't try to define properties for strings, booleans and numbers, this simply doesn't work.

```
var a = {}; //this is a common object
a.test = "abc"; 
console.log(a.test);//will print "abc"

var b = "zzzz"; //declaring a string primitive
b.test = "abc"; //trying to add a property to this string, we're treating our primitive as an object
console.log(b.test);//will print undefined
```

Comment: OK, when I change obj.str to a new String("string me!"), it works. So, it looks like if I want to add a $error, I should change my primitives to their object equivalents.

Comment: Exactly, just because you're instantiating a new String object, not declaring a primitive.